# How to pass arguments / parameters to the npm-script using npmExecuteScripts?

Tags: sap-business-technology-platform, sap-project-piper

I'm trying to run the npm-script from the Jenkins pipeline via the SAP Project Piper's [`npmExecuteScripts`](https://www.project-piper.io/steps/npmExecuteScripts):

```yaml
npmExecuteScripts:
    runScripts: ["testScript"]
```

That works! Now, I want to pass some arguments to my script.
According to the Project Piper documentation, there is a property [`scriptOptions`](https://www.project-piper.io/steps/npmExecuteScripts/#scriptoptions), which cares about passing arguments to the called script:

> *Options are passed to all runScripts calls separated by a `--`. `./piper npmExecuteScripts --runScripts ci-e2e --scriptOptions` `--tag1` will correspond to `npm run ci-e2e -- --tag1`*

Unfortunately, I can't figure out what is the proper syntax for that command.
I've tried several combinations of using `scriptOptions`, e.g.:

```yaml
scriptOptions: ["myArg"]
scriptOptions: ["myArg=myVal"]
```

and many others, but still no desired outcome!

How can I call an npm-script and pass arguments / parameters to the script using the Project Piper's `npmExecuteScripts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue, it's important to bear in mind that in contrast to the regular argument-value mapping via the `npm_config_`-prefix, the SAP Project Piper `scriptOptions` doesn't perform a mapping and passes an array of argument-value pairs «as is» instead, and then this array can be picked up via `process.argv`.

The Jenkins pipeline configuration:

```yaml
npmExecuteScripts:
    runScripts: ["testScript"]
    scriptOptions: ["arg1=Val1", "arg2=Val2"]
```

package.json:

```json
"scripts": {
    "testScript": "node ./testScript.mjs"
}
```

The server-side script:

```js
/**
 * @param {Array.<String>} args - array of console input arguments to be parsed
 */
const testScript = function testScript(args) {…}

testScript(process.argv.slice(2));
```

P.S. Just to compare, the regular way to pass an argument's value to the npm-script looks like:

```shell
npm run testScript --arg=Val
```

and the server-side script:

```json
"testScript": "echo \"*** My argument's value: ${npm_config_arg} ***\""
```

The output:

> *** My argument's value: Val ***

The npm-script engine performs an argument-value mapping under the hood by using the `npm_config_`-prefix.